# PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript

I need to transfer the values from a PHP array into a JavaScript array so that it can be used in my application, I have managed to get up to this:

```
var Descriptions = array(<?php 
                foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                $ID = $task['ID'];
                $description = $task['description'];

                echo $ID . "[" . $description . "]" . ",";  
                }

                ?>);
```

and it works fine except for one thing: I dont know how to tell PHP to not put a comma after the last array value. The extra comma is causing a syntax error so it breaks my code.

Thanks in advance for any ideas,
RayQuang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way:

```
for($i = 0, $c = count($tasks); $i < $c; $i++) {
   $task = $tasks[$i];
   ...
   echo $ID . "[" . $description . "]" . (($i != $c-1) ? "," : ''); 
}
```

There are obviously other ways of accomplishing this, one way would be to build up a string and then use the `trim()` function:

```
$tasks_str = '';
foreach(...) {
   ...
   $tasks_str .= ...
}

echo trim($tasks_str, ',');
```

Or, (my favorite), you could build up an array and then use `implode` on it:

```
$tasks_array = array();
foreach(...) {
   ...
   $tasks_array[] = ...
}

echo implode(',', $tasks_array);
```

Comment: As i said - this is dangerous, you need to make sure you escape certain characters in the $ID and $description variables before outputting them into a JavaScript block. json_encode already does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

don't try to build it manually, use json_encode

Comment: I can't understand why you would *ever* want to use any other method?

Answer (score 1):

```
var Descriptions = <?=json_encode($tasks);?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var DescriptionsString = <?php 
            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            $ID = $task['ID'];
            $description = $task['description'];

            echo $ID . "[" . $description . "]" . ",";  
            }

            ?>;
var Descriptions = DescriptionsString.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var Descriptions = array(<?php 
                $str = '';
                foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                $ID = $task['ID'];
                $description = $task['description'];

                $str .= $ID . "[" . $description . "]" . ",";  
                }
                 echo trim($str,',');      
                ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not one to miss out on a trend:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $ID = $task['ID'];
    $description = $task['description'];

    $out[] = $ID . "[" . $description . "]";  
}
echo implode(',', $out);
```

Using [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).